# Having problem in sending the data to next page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am developing a application in which I have a recyclerview  which displays some profile of peoples in cardview. I am having a problem that when I am trying to send the data on next page it is giving a exception. I tried to remove the exception but didn't got any success.

This is the code for search profile:

```
public class Search_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    Context context;
    public Search_Profile() {

    }

    FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search__profile);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Search_Profile.this));
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Dashboard.Database_Path);

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                .setPageSize(1)
                .build();
        DatabasePagingOptions<User> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(databaseReference, config, User.class)
                .build();


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false),context) {

                };
            }
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull User user) {

                viewHolder.setItem(user, i);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        // Do your loading animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:
                        // Stop Animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        //Reached end of Data set
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        retry();
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                super.onError(databaseError);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                // Handle Error
                retry();
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapter.refresh();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    //Stop Listening Adapter
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

This the code for view holder:

```
class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Context context;
    List<User> MainImageUploadInfoList;

    public TextView FirstNameTextView;
    public TextView DateTextView;
    public TextView HeightTextView;
    public TextView EducationTextView;
    public TextView OccupationTextView;
    public TextView UserIDTextView;
    public Button send_invitation,shortlist_profile;
    public TextView income;
    public TextView city_state;
    public TextView hobbies;
    public TextView marital_status;
    public TextView family_members;
    public TextView mothers_name;
    public TextView fathers_name;
    public TextView fathers_occupation;
    public TextView mothers_occupation;
    public CardView mCardView;
    User user=new User();



public UserViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context=context;

        itemView.setTag(user.getUser_id());
        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        FirstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        DateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        HeightTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        EducationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        OccupationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        UserIDTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.income);
        city_state = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_state);
        hobbies = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hobbies);
        marital_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marital_status);
        family_members = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.family_members);
        mothers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_name);
        fathers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_name);
        fathers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_occupation);
        mothers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_occupation);
        send_invitation = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendinvitation);
        shortlist_profile=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortlistprofile);
        send_invitation=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendinvitation);
        shortlist_profile=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortlistprofile);

        shortlist_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                FirebaseUser user1 = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userId = user1.getUid();
                Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://baghbanshadi-25553.firebaseio.com/");
                Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("User");
                User user =new User();
                String user_id=UserIDTextView.getText().toString();
                assert user != null;
                user.setUser_id(user_id);
                userRef.child(userId).child("Shortlisted").child(user_id).setValue(user_id);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Profile Shortlisted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int i = (int) itemView.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), Integer.toString(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (getLayoutPosition() == 0) {
                    final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                    it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("positionGroup", i);
                    context.startActivity(it);
                }
                else if (getLayoutPosition() == 1) {

                    final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                    it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("positionGroup", i);
                    context.startActivity(it);
                } else if (getLayoutPosition() == 2) {
                    final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                    it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("positionGroup", i);
                    context.startActivity(it);
                }
  }
        });

    }
 public void setItem(User user, int i){

        mCardView.setTag(i);
        FirstNameTextView.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " " + user.getLast_name());
        DateTextView.setText(user.getDate());
        HeightTextView.setText(user.getHeight());
        EducationTextView.setText(user.getHighest_education());
        OccupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
        UserIDTextView.setText(user.getUser_id());
        income.setText(user.getIncome());
        city_state.setText(user.getCity_state());
        hobbies.setText(user.getHobbies());
        marital_status.setText(user.getMarital_status());
        family_members.setText(user.getFamily_members());
        mothers_name.setText(user.getMothers_name());
        fathers_name.setText(user.getFathers_name());
        fathers_occupation.setText(user.getFathers_occupation());
        mothers_occupation.setText(user.getMothers_occupation());
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: accentra.in, PID: 4655
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at accentra.in.UserViewHolder$2.onClick(UserViewHolder.java:112)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4655 SIG: 9
Process 4655 terminated.
```

Comment: use this getApplicationContext()

Comment: context  giving the error `context.startActivity(it);`. Replace it with `v.getContext()`

Comment: just a suggestion you can pass whole list from one activity to another no need to put each and every item in putextra...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Context null, you need to replace `context.startActivity(it)` with `itemView.getContext()
.startActivity()`

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)  you just forgot to pass the object, it should be itemView.getContext().startActivity(it);

Answer (score 0):

Context is null. You need to provide context when you construct the class *UserViewHolder*.

```
private final Context context;

public UserViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: I can see from the code you provided than you haven't.

Comment: You've since added this to your code, since that was the solution mark this answer as correct.